# Youtube video in popup doesnt stop playing when window closed

Tags: jquery, api, youtube

So basically, I have a pop up code that makes a div pop up. Inside that, there is a youtube video player. Everything works, until I close the window, I can still hear the music in background meaning that the video is still playing. I want to stop it.
I did some research and fell on the youtube API's, but it still doesnt work.

Here is my code for the div

```
echo "<div id='popupContact'>";
echo "<a id='popupContactClose'>x</a>";
echo "<div><h1>" .$row['title']. "</h1></div>";
echo "<p id='contactArea'>";
if($row[type] == "image")
echo "<img src='gallery/" .$row['path']. "' alt='" .$row['title']. "'/>";
else
echo "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='http://www.youtube.com/v/" .$row['path']."?        enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
echo "<br/><br/>" .$row['description']. "</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='backgroundPopup'></div>";
```

And here is the code for the pop up:

```
//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){

//LOADING POPUP
//Click the button event!
$("#button").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    centerPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
});

//CLOSING POPUP
//Click the x event!
$("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
    disablePopup();
});
//Click out event!
$("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
    disablePopup();
});
//Press Escape event!
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup();
    }
});

});

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup(){
//disables popup only if it is enabled
if(popupStatus==1){
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
$("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
popupStatus = 0;
stop();
}
}
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
alert("YAY");
ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
}

function stop() {
if (ytplayer) {
ytplayer.stopVideo();
}
}
```

Thank you,
Ara

Comment: I don't see the code for the function `loadPopup()` that is called when the #button is clicked..

Comment: function loadPopup(){
 //loads popup only if it is disabled
 if(popupStatus==0){
  $("#backgroundPopup").css({
   "opacity": "0.7"
  });
  $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
  popupStatus = 1;
 }
}

Comment: Did you review the documentation I listed in my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking over the [Youtube Documentation(iframe)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and I think you are mixing up the different api's

On the [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)  it states

> We recommend using SWFObject to embed any players that will be accessed using the JavaScript API.

But you are using an iframe.  So I think you need to create a function called

`function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`

Which has several lines of code to setup everything along with other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Variable scope. You only ever define `ytplayer` inside your `onYouTubePlayerReady()` function, and don't return the value. When that function returns, the ytplayer value is destroyed.

You need to define the variable OUTSIDE of the function:

```
var ytplayer;   // now a global variable.
function onYouTubePlayerReadye(playerID) {
   ytplayer = document.getElementById('ytplayer');
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work though....I think the onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) never gets called. I placed test alert in the function and it never gets called